# Does the use of senses require any knowledge about what is sensed?

Tags: epistemology, mind-body, perception, locke, sense-and-reference

Does the use of any sense (hearing, sight, pitch, proprioception, heat/cold, pain) require any knowledge about what is sensed in order to be used effectively?

I phrased this poorly.

I really mean "does understanding of senses" rather than "use" of senses. For example, a plant or virus may use sensory input, but is not aware of those senses. Humans and many animals actually perceive the senses; that is, we have some "picture" or understanding of what we are sensing.

To clarify:

If someone was paralyzed from the neck down due to a spinal cord severing, they would still kick their leg out when you tap their knee (it is a reflex in the spinal cord). This seems to be the case with some other reactions. When we wince at a very loud sound, or jump a bit, I think it is plausible to suggest we *react* before we have an awareness of the sound. So, it is possible to "use" the sound without an understanding or perception of it. This is not what I mean.

However, in a couple milliseconds, we have an awareness of the sound. We also have an awareness of our vision and touch. It seems like there is an additional "step" with senses beyond merely reacting to them; we also perceive (see, hear, smell, taste, etc.) them.

This second category is what I am wondering about. Can we "effectively use" (i.e., have some awareness or perception of) senses, without first having some knowledge about the sense?

Does perception of a sense require knowledge for the "perceiving" part to happen?

Comment: It depends on you're a Bayesian or frequentist, if former you always need to require some prior or assumed knowledge about what is sensed in order to try to more efficiently use it. If the latter then you purely sense what is sensed and then use it by your gained experience entirely, not unlike a lovely newborn baby, no justified true knowledge in philosophical sense is required at all since your belief content from the said experience could be totally false...

Comment: How could it possibly be otherwise? For example, you obviously can't read this sentence using your sight except by knowing what the squiggle pictures mean.

Comment: This depends on your definition of sense. Certain plants (sunflowers) exhibit [heliotropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliotropism) (they follow the sun). So the plant senses the sun and alters its position. Plants have no knowledge of the sun (or anything) yet it senses and responds.

Comment: Excellent question, it's been a historical philosophical issue related to the question of just how objective our sensory data (if such a thing exists) is. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sense-data to get yourself started. Also https://neuroscience.stanford.edu/news/reality-constructed-your-brain-here-s-what-means-and-why-it-matters

Comment: @JD Even if the sensory data was not objective or even if it was made up or hallucinated, shouldn't effective interpretation of that data require a beforehand understanding of what is being sensed? Otherwise, I struggle to see how the information could be interpreted or used. Sensory data --> knowledge concept of what is sensed --> interpretation/understanding of the sensory data

Comment: That depends on an understanding of interpretation, knowledge, and interpretation. Let me take a stab at answering in a few minutes.

Comment: Put your hand on a hot stove and see what happens. Why do reflexes invariably cause us to correctly pull *away* from danger? Where did that come in?

Comment: @ScottRowe I see your point (but actually, in the case of a burn, a reflex arc is activated in our spinal cord and we move our hand before we are aware of the sensation). Technicalities aside, I agree with you. A critic may say that that is merely an instinct (that the sense is not understood before use), but I am not that critic, so I can't really defend that.

Comment: I suggest you close this question and ask a new one. The problem with the kind of major edits that you have made is that they invalidate answers given beforehand, which just makes the site look like it is full of irrelevant answers. Also, you need to clarify what you mean by knowledge. What sort of knowledge? Knowledge about what, exactly?

Comment: If you were dropped on an alien planet, where nothing was like anything you have ever experienced, your senses would still work, even though you had zero knowledge of what you were sensing, so clearly you can't mean knowledge about what it is you are interacting with. Given that, what other 'knowledge' do you mean?

Comment: @MarcoOcram Any knowledge. Any sort of understanding.

Comment: This is one of the topics of Merleau-Ponty's Phenomenology of Perception, which I never managed to finish. His take is that perception is always active, in the sense that we don't just see things, we *look* for things out there, actively seeking and interpreting signals emanating from objects. There's always some interpretation going on, some theory-ladden intent in the looking.

Comment: I agree with Marco Ocram and recommend to repeat your interesting question under a new title and with a more focused text.

Comment: @JoWehler I will do that

Answer (score 1):

I'm beginning with the caveat that your question in the title and at the end of the post are different conceptually because of the use of "used effectively", and that I will be answering this question, and not the question in the title. Furthermore, I'm not going to do justice to the issue, but hopefully this will provide some direction.

**The question of whether or not our knowledge contaminates our interpretation of our senses is an important question that is related to the notion of [theory-ladenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness).** From WP:

> In the philosophy of science, observations are said to be "theory-laden" when they are affected by the theoretical presuppositions held by the investigator. The thesis of theory-ladenness is most strongly associated with the late 1950s and early 1960s work of Norwood Russell Hanson, Thomas Kuhn, and Paul Feyerabend, and was probably first put forth (at least implicitly) by Pierre Duhem about 50 years earlier.

**The consensus has been established in the philosophy of science that our theoretical knowledge does affect what we see in the broad picture.** If we have a theory that is near and dear to us, what we believe at an epistemological level, affects what we see in the observations of our sense data. But let's take a close look at your question:

> Does the use of any sense (hearing, sight, pitch, proprioception, heat/cold, pain) require any knowledge about what is sensed in order to be used effectively?

I would argue the answer, if you accept the arguments that lead to theory-ladenness, demands a yes because "used effectively" essentially suggests that there are teleological aims that our epistemological labors pursue. The best way to understand this is through an explication of the cognitive bias known as [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). From WP:

> Confirmation bias is the tendency to search for, interpret, favor, and recall information in a way that confirms or supports one's prior beliefs or values.

So, **on multiple levels if using our senses effectively is understood at making observations to arive at scientific explanation through inference to best explanation, helping to ensure particularly we are accounting for any possible defeaters, then our senses are affected on several levels.** On the level of perception below conscious awareness, our minds may be drawn to one set of distinguishing phenomenological features whether you call them qualities, qualia, or tropes. On the level of observation, our attention may be drawn to one set of phenomena rather than another. On the level of converting our observations to language, we may choose words that prejudice someone else's interpretation of our observation in our rhetorical favor. On the level of methodology, our choice of tools affects what sort of observation our senses are exposed to.

So, from the level of perception to the level of observation in the pursuit of methodological naturalism, to effectively use our senses are knowledge informs how our sensory apparatus is integrated into our subconscious and conscious experience.

Comment: Come to me, all who are theory-laden.

Comment: @ScottRowe That sounds like Jesus with his Sermon at the Lab.

Comment: This demonstrates that our existing knowledge colors our perception. I totally agree. But is knowledge requisite to perception in the first place?

Comment: @BigMistake Would you say a baby has awareness of its visual sensation (perceives something) when they start to smile at the appearance of their parents' faces? If so, what kind of "knowledge" should we ascribe to them? Sellars and related works may be a good address to start as historically, he is one of the first important philosophers who went really deep into the sensation-perception divide and how knowledge and language are needed for and intertwined with that.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Exactly. That's thr question I'm asking. I would argue that newborns can move (not very effectively), they can diffentiate between same or different numbers of tones and shapes respectively, they can detect objects and faces, etc. so they perceive things. I'm wondering if other people agree, and if we can ascribe any sort of knowledge to that

Comment: @BigMistake Ryle in his *The Concept of Mind* raises the claim to the existence of [knowledge how (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-how/) in which knowledge can be seen not as JTB but as in activity. In this sense, their is a feedback loop between a baby's physical activities and the senses where the senses inform motion, for instance, but the goal of the motion directs the senses.

Answer (score 1):

Before attempting to answer I would like to rephrase and focus a bit your question:

> Sense perceptions are consciously registered. While a visual stimulus
> can also be answered by the organism without conscious registration,
> just by reflex. Is there a benefit for humans due to **conscious**
> registration?

We know from neurobiology that a visual stimulus is processed step by step. It is forwarded to several  neural areals, e.g. primary visual cortex, secondary visual cortex and finally the associative visual cortex. Not every stimulus is forwarded to these areals, others are filtered off. The **conscious** registration, i.e. the visual perception, arises in the end when the electrical excitation circulates forward and backwards within the thalamo-cortical system.

The **benefit** of conscious processing within the thalamo-cortical system: The pattern of excitation can be compared to those patterns, which are already stored in the neo-cortex. This allows to identify the pattern together with its stored positive or negative assessment. Hence the organism may favour a response which has been **successful** in the past.

A good overview about conscious mental processes is “Christof Koch: Consciousness” (2012)

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was trying to convey!

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge is based on memory. We must understand how memory works. Memory is a combination of sense consciousness, sense organ and subject of sense organ , for example memory of taste arises when tongue consciousness, tongue and food combine. If the combination has been visited before, it gives rise to memory and thus you remember the taste. However if something new comes up which you have never tasted before then combination leaves an impression in the consciousness which gets recalled if it is tasted again in future. Therefore no prior knowledge is required for senses to work.

Knowledge gained is impermanent. It arises , changes and vanishes. We again condition the senses to regain the knowledge if it has been lost. There is no absolute knowledge as all conditioning of pain and pleasure , love and hate , good and bad , smart and stupid etc are impermanent.

Comment: But some things are pretty darn stubborn.

Comment: Surely you have memory of what you've tasted before, even if it's not exactly new, right? You remember the general picture/gist of taste.

Comment: @BigMistake memory is not stored anywhere. It comes up when mind consciousness, brain and subject of meditation meet.

Comment: @DheerajVerma Yes it is. This is why people with neurological damage to the hippocampus have memory loss. Of course, there are other areas of the brain involved with memory (including to help store memory) but it is certainly stored in areas of the brain.

Comment: @BigMistake Brain participates in remembering but is not solely responsible for it .

Comment: @DheerajVerma Cars participate in driving but are not solely responsible for it (requires gas, good terrain). But, we all say that cars drive. Similarly, the brain remembers. Driving is done by the car, and "happens" in the car, for all practical purposes.